# Batch file to copy certain file types from certain subdirectories to one folder

Tags: batch-file, copy

Looking to copy all files with extension *.cpp in "development" subfolders to new directory.

For example, C:\source has 10 folders named A1 to A10.  Each A folder has subfolder such as development, pending, released.  I want to extract all *.cpp from all development subfolders and place in C:\destination.

Example C:\source\A1\development\ folder contains file one.cpp 
C:\source\A1\released\ folder contains two.cpp

I want only files *.cpp that are in path that contain development name.
So in this example only one.cpp should be copied to newfolder

I can name these files from a cmd prompt:
dir /s /b *.cpp | findstr /i /m "development" > outfile.txt

(Note that dir command above is searching only filenames, not the contents of the files!)

Guess I could take the outfile.txt and run another batch file

[Batch script to copy files listed in text file from a folder and its subfolders to a new location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38128220/batch-script-to-copy-files-listed-in-text-file-from-a-folder-and-its-subfolders)

However, there must be easier way.

BTW:

[DOS Batch file to copy certain file types from subdirectories to one folder with rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14089371/dos-batch-file-to-copy-certain-file-types-from-subdirectories-to-one-folder-with)

does not allow limiting to subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=132448.0):

But does need to be run from a batch file.

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /i /M "glossary" *.txt') do copy "%%A" C:\destination
```

EDIT:

No need for findstr for just file names, so I've used your initial dir search, and combined it with the for statement. Works  for me :)

`for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /b *development*.cpp') do copy "%%A" C:\destination`

EDIT2:

Right, so this should be it, now the for statement runs with the folders inside the dir as a variable. Note: it does generate false positives that you can filter out with an if exists statement, but I'm sure you can experiment with that yourself:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\source\*"') do copy %%D\development\*.cpp C:\destination
```

EDIT3:

In case you wanted to find several .cpp's in your mystery dir :)

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%D in ('dir /b /s /a:d "C:\source\*"') do (for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir /s /b "%%D\development\*.cpp"') do copy "%%A" C:\destination)
```

Comment: I'm trying to find filename with development in the name not in the contents.  The 'findstr /i /M "glossary" *.txt' searches contents of files in this line, but when used as argument in dir it searches only the filename.

Comment: You can always clear the glossary part, and use `*development*.txt`?

Comment: can you type out exact new command?  findstr /i /m   *development*.txt doesn't work, it needs an argument for filename.

Comment: dir /s /b *development*.cpp returns file not found.  dir /s /b *development* lists full path of folder names that contain development.

Comment: Have you copied the batch file to the directory that you want to search from, and entered `*development*.cpp` I tested this, with txt files, and it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157027/discussion-between-equalizer-and-itchi).

Comment: Note that path is C:\source\A1\development\dummy.cpp and I am searching for two criteria: 1) folder path that contains "development" and 2) file has *.cpp extension

Comment: My mistake, initially I thought you were probing for files containing "development" If you run the for statement on the folder as a variable, you should get what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! It didn't work at first because my folders called development1.  I tried ('dir /s /b "%%D\development*\*.cpp"'), but doesn't like wildcard * after development.  Different syntax possible?

Comment: @equalizer Wildcarding is not very easy for directory names, hence the nested for loop, it will only accept wildcards at the end of the statement too. If all of your folders are called development1, it would be easier to add that to the search term, alternatively you can try `%%D\development*\*.cpp` But I don't think this would work. Might need to nest another for loop?